# customfields data is required (cart66 + wordpress error message)

Tags: wordpress

I have installed cart66 professional in my wordpress site.

i have configured cart66 with payleap.

in the checkout page, when complete the order by filling all the required information, and clicking the 'Complete Order' button link, after little process it displays following message.

```
we're sorry

your order could not be completed for the following reasons:

customfields data is required
```

do anyone have any idea about this?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your theme you need to insert custom field data which required.
for ex.
price is define custom field then add custom field.

price : 34$

Fore more info...
http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields